# To coil or fold or cause to coil or fold

Tags: difference, transitivity

TheFreeDictionary says about "convolute":

> *intr. & tr.v.
>   To coil or fold or cause to coil or fold in overlapping whorls.*

You can see that article here - [convolute](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/convolute)

Can you explain to me why there is not enough to say just "to coil or fold", but there is also world "cause"? I mean why English people distinguish "to coil" and "cause to coil"?

Comment: Because things like *proteins* can fold ***intransitively*** (we don't normally assume that some external "agent" ***causes*** them to fold). That's why the definition specifically says ***intr. & tr.v.***

Comment: Bear in mind that this term is often used as an image and as an adjective: a convoluted problem, a convoluted situation. You won't see: The whorls do not convolute.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I have no idea what your comment means.

Comment: @Lambie: I wasn't familiar with [***ergative***](https://www.thoughtco.com/ergative-grammar-term-1690608#:~:text=In%20grammar%20and%20morphology%2C%20ergative,state%2C%20position%2C%20or%20movement.) - *a verb that can be used in a construction in which the same noun phrase can serve as a subject **when the verb is intransitive**, and as a direct object **when the verb is transitive.*** But that's essentially what I meant, and it looks to me like what the OP needs to know here.

Answer (score 1):

The word "fold" can be used in two ways:

> I fold the bed. (transitive)
>
> The bed folds for storage. (intranitive)

Such verbs are sometimes called ergative.  The dictionary definition suggests that "convolute" can also be used both transitively or intransitively (but it is a rare word as a verb, it's more common as an adjective "convoluted")

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of what verb is being referenced. `I.E. am I doing the [verb] or am I doing something that makes the object [verb] ?`

"To coil" is as if I am doing the coiling. **Example: "I coil the spaghetti."**

"To cause to coil", I am not doing the coiling, but somehow it still coils. **Example: "I boil water and cause the spaghetti to coil."**